# Ajax submission does not output results from multi-steps form results in same page in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type

I'm trying to make a multi-step forms with radio buttons, which will be used to filter some custom posts, using ajax. ***[Here](http://formazione-salesforce.enigen.it/prova-2/)*** you can see an example. Currently, once the user complete and submit the form, the page re-charge and apparently the form is submitted, but it show the form again and no the results.

What I have so far:

1. **An external (not inline) jQuery file with the ajax code**

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
                   var left, opacity, scale; 
                   var animating; 

                   $(".next").click(function () {
                       if (animating) return false;
                       animating = true;

                       current_fs = $(this).parent();
                       next_fs = $(this).parent().next();


                       $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active")
                       $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).addClass("done");


                       next_fs.show();

                       current_fs.animate({
                           opacity: 0
                       }, {
                           step: function (now, mx) {

                               scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                               left = (now * 50) + "%";
                               opacity = 1 - now;
                               current_fs.css({
                                   'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                                   'position': 'absolute'
                               });
                               next_fs.css({
                                   'left': left,
                                   'opacity': opacity
                               });
                           },
                           duration: 800,
                           complete: function () {
                               current_fs.hide();
                               animating = false;
                           },

                       });
                   });



                   $(".previous").click(function () {
                       if (animating) return false;
                       animating = true;

                       current_fs = $(this).parent();
                       previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

                       $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");


                       previous_fs.show();

                       current_fs.animate({
                           opacity: 0
                       }, {
                           step: function (now, mx) {

                               scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;

                               left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";

                               opacity = 1 - now;
                               current_fs.css({
                                   'left': left
                               });
                               previous_fs.css({
                                   'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                                   'opacity': opacity
                               });
                           },
                           duration: 800,
                           complete: function () {
                               current_fs.hide();
                               animating = false;
                           },

                       });
                   });

                   $('.del').hide();
                     $('.scelt-con').hide();

                   $("input[name='prodotto']").change(function () {
                       var strText = $("input[name='prodotto']:checked").val();
                       var result = strText;
                       $('#prodotto').text(result);
                       $('#uno').show(500);
                       $ ('.prod').show(500);
                       return false;

                   });

                   $("input[name='livello']").change(function () {
                       var strText = $("input[name='livello']:checked").val();
                       var result = strText;
                       $('#livello').text(result);
                       $('#due').show(500);
                       $ ('.liv').show(500);
                   });

                   $("input[name='ruolo']").change(function () {
                       var strText = $("input[name='ruolo']:checked").val();
                       var result = strText;
                       $('#ruolo').text(result);
                       $('#tre').show(500);
                       $ ('.role').show(500);
                   });

                   $("input[name='stato']").change(function () {
                       var strText = $("input[name='stato']:checked").val(); 
                       var result = strText;
                       $('#stato').text(result);
                       $('#qua').show(500);
                       $ ('.sta').show(500);
                   });

   $("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

   var form = $('#msform');
   var url = ajax_object.ajax_url;
   var fdata = {};
   fdata['action'] = 'process_form';
   fdata['prodotto'] = form.find('input[name="prodotto"]').val();
   fdata['livello'] = form.find('input[name="livello"]').val();
   fdata['ruolo'] = form.find('input[name="ruolo"]').val();
   fdata['stato'] = form.find('input[name="stato"]').val();

   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: fdata,
          success: function(resp)
          {
              var res_tab = $("#res-tab");

              res_tab.empty();
              res_tab.append(resp.data);

              $("fieldset").hide();
              res_tab.show();
          },
          error: function(error) {
              console.log(error);
          },
       });

       e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
   });
     });
   ```
2. **The js file enqueue and the ajax calling in my** ***functions.php***

   ```
     function enqueue_radio() {
           if (is_page_template('modello-2.php')){ 
     wp_enqueue_script( 'radio', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/radio.js', array('jquery'), '', false );
             wp_localize_script( 'radio', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
                  }
                }
               add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_radio' );



   function process_form() { 

   global $wpdb;
   $prodotto = $_POST["prodotto"];       
   $livello = $_POST["livello"];       
   $ruolo = $_POST["ruolo"];       
   $stato = $_POST["stato"]; 
   ?>
   <div id="res-tab" class="row">
   <?php

       $args = array( 
                   'post_type' => 'corsi',
                   'posts_per_page' => -1,
                   'orderby' => 'title',
                   'order'   => 'ASC',
                   'tax_query' => array(
                           array(
                               'taxonomy' => 'prodotto',
                               'field' => 'name',
                               'terms' => $prodotto,
                               ),
                           array(
                               'taxonomy' => 'livello',
                               'field' => 'name',
                               'terms' => $livello,
                               ),
                           array(
                               'taxonomy' => 'ruolo',
                               'field' => 'name',
                               'terms' => $ruolo,
                               ),
                           array(
                               'taxonomy' => 'stato',
                               'field' => 'name',
                               'terms' => $stato,
                               ),        
                           ) 
                       );
       $soluzioni = new WP_Query($args);
           if ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
               while ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
               $soluzioni->the_post(); ?>

       <div class="col-md-6 largo">
           <div class="blocco">
               <h3 style="font-size:20px;line-height:23px;"><?php the_title();?><br/>
               <?php  
               $codice = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_corsi_codice', true);
               echo '( '.$codice .' )'; ?></h3>
               <p>
                   <?php the_content();?>
               </p>
               <div class="dettagli row">
                   <div class="col-md-6 no-pads">
                       <h5>PRODOTTO</h5>
                       <p>
                           <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'prodotto', '',', ', '' ); ?>
                       </p>
                       <h5>AUDIENCE</h5>
                       <p>
                           <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ruolo',  '',', ', ''); ?>
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6 no-pads">
                       <h5>MODALITà DI EROGAZIONE</h5>
                       <p>
                           <?php  $modalita = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_corsi_modalita', true);
               echo $modalita; ?>
                       </p>
                       <h5>DURATA</h5>
                       <p>
                           <?php  $durata = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_corsi_durata', true);
               echo $durata; ?>
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <a href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>">
                       <button>DETTAGLI</button>
                   </a>
               </div>

           </div>
       </div>
       <?php   } 

       wp_reset_postdata(); } 
       else {
               echo '<br/>NO POST FOUND';
           }

   ?>
   </div>

   <?php         

     //  wp_send_json_success( $soluzioni);   

       wp_die();
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_form', 'process_form' );
   ```

   3. **The template part to display the form**

http://formazione-salesforce.enigen.it/prova-2/

Comment: Form page not loading.. getting error

Comment: My bad. Error fixed

Comment: You are using form submit. you have to call the ajax function in onclick.

Comment: you need to change the input type `submit` to `button` in 4th step.

`<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value=">`

Comment: ok, now it does recharge and the form disappear, but it doesn't show te results. I think I did something wrong in the functions part. Thanks

Comment: There is no div has this id `$("#res-tab");`. you need to change `var res_tab = $("#res-tab");` to  `var res_tab = $("#res-cont");`

Comment: im getting this response in ajax `<div id="res-tab" class="row">
<br/>NO POST FOUND</div>`

Comment: Yes, I get that too now but it does not output in the page